# XAMPP enable PUT method

Tags: webserver, apache-http-server, xampp

I'm using XAMPP on Windows and I'm trying to user the HTTP Put method. For some reason, Apache is configured in such a way that the PUT method is blocked. How can I enable the HTTP PUT (and also Delete) method in Apache?